# Elastic Search-Java: Not able to recreate index again after deleting that index

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I am trying to recreate index after deleting the XYZ index but it through weird exception.

**Problem Statement:**
There are two indices 
**ABC** with fields as:

> ```
> {...
>     "internalId": {
>                   "store": false,
>                   "type": "integer"
>               },
>     ...}
> ```

And for other **XYZ** with fields as:

> ```
> {...
> "internalId": {
>               "store": false,
>               "type": "keyword"
>           },
> ...}
> ```

Now whenever it tries to create index the XYZ through code

```
private void saveEsXYZ(EsXYZ esxyz){
    try {

        if (recreateIndex) {
            esXYZRepo.deleteIndex();  ---- There is no problem with this code.
            esXYZRepo.createIndex();  ---- When trying to create then throw IllegalArgumentException
        }
            glLogger.info("indexing xyz for id : {}", esxyz.getId());
            esXYZRepo.index(esxyz);
        glLogger.info("updated  records ");
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        glLogger.info("Exception occoured in EsXYZ ", ex);
    }
}
```

then it throws:
    10-Jan-2020 12:09:29.462 ERROR localhost-startStop-1 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.esXYZRepo' defined in URL [jar:file:/path
/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/webapps/xyz/WEB-INF/lib/xyzRepo-1.0.jar!/com/xyz/sky30/es/repo/XYZRepo.class]: **Invocation of init method failed; nested excepti
on is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mapper [internalId] cannot be changed from type [integer] to [keyword]
        at** org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1634) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEAS
E.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.j
ar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar
:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RE
LEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4
.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.ja
r:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mapper [internalId] cannot be changed from type [integer] to [keyword]
        at** org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MappedFieldType.checkTypeName(MappedFieldType.java:147) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MappedFieldType.checkCompatibility(MappedFieldType.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldTypeLookup.checkCompatibility(FieldTypeLookup.java:128) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldTypeLookup.copyAndAddAll(FieldTypeLookup.java:94) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.internalMerge(MapperService.java:398) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.internalMerge(MapperService.java:334) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:258) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$1.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:371) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateUpdateTask.execute(ClusterStateUpdateTask.java:45) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.executeTasks(ClusterService.java:633) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.calculateTaskOutputs(ClusterService.java:611) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.runTasks(ClusterService.java:570) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService$ClusterServiceTaskBatcher.run(ClusterService.java:262) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher.runIfNotProcessed(TaskBatcher.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher$BatchedTask.run(TaskBatcher.java:188) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]

Any Answers will be Highly appreciable.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you verified XYZ is deleted before recreating it?

Comment: Yes, It was got deleted. But getting the problem with the creation of the index.

Comment: Can you share your XYZRepo.class?

Comment: The problem got resolved by changing the type of field internalId from keyword to integer. But I want to understand why it's not working for keyword type. Is there any field schema sharing between these indices, or not?

Comment: @AshishKarn Are you sure that these are different indices & different types ? if you are using the same index with different types mapping the same field to different data types, your code is bound to fail, keep in mind that types are a logical data separation which elasticsearch provides, under the hood lucene stores the data from different types in the same index, so if you change/overwrite the data type of the same field, you will get IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Looks like a refresh issue. Add a wait (1s) between the delete and create and retry please.

Comment: @kumarD Thanks for the explanation but they are different indices.

Comment: @LeBigCat Thread.sleep(1500) means the 1.5-sec wait is already implemented.